# Optimize TSQL query with 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, query-optimization

I need to get all the runs from the database, but need to mark if there is an error for this run.

3 Tables:

- Runs: contains the runs)
- Runfiles: contains the file ids that were processed during a run
- Messages: contains errors, warnings, ...

Can this query be optimized any further?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 runid, 
            start, 
            end, 
            userid, 
            CASE 
              WHEN EXISTS(SELECT rf.fk_fileid 
                          FROM   runfiles rf 
                          WHERE  rf.fk_runid = r.runid 
                                 AND EXISTS(SELECT m.messageid 
                                            FROM   messages m 
                                            WHERE  m.fk_fileid = 
                                                   rf.fk_fileid 
                                                   AND m.fk_statusid = 4)) 
            THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
            END                 AS ContainsError
FROM   runs r 
ORDER  BY start DESC
```

Please don't comment on the table names, they were translated for this question.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the execution plan and add appropriate indexes

Comment: What does "optimized" mean? If you're asking about performance then you should include the execution plan from the query. If you're asking about improving readability or maintainability then the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to compare different options.  Have you tried Left Joins on runfiles and messages?

Comment: Also, if you're using SQL Server, try the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Comment: Optimizing for improved performance. The query now requires about 3 seconds to run on the test machine for only 2500 records. I'll try the database engine tuning advisor.

Comment: @Narnian: My first try had some joins in it, but it took ages. The exists function is quite performant. For me personally, it's just bad design not to include the runid as a foreign key in the messages table but I'm not allowed to change the database at this point. Thanks for all the replies so far!

Comment: @Nullius I have a blog post that may help:  http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/sql-server-database-optimization-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: The query look fine to me, the performance problem is probably because of lack of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
     r.runid
    ,r.start
    ,r.[end]
    ,r.userid
    ,CASE WHEN m.messageid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ContainsError
FROM runs r
LEFT JOIN runfiles rf
    ON rf.fk_runid = r.runid
LEFT JOIN [messages] m
    ON m.fk_fileid = rf.fk_fileid
    AND m.fk_statusid = 4
ORDER BY r.start DESC
```

Anything in the select list is ran for each row in the result set. This means that the nested subquery in your `CASE` statement is being executed for each of those `TOP 1000` rows.

Using left joins and a `CASE` statement to check if the primary key is null allow the entire statement to be evaluated as a set, which SQL Server is built to do. It should perform better this way.

Comment: The relation Run <-> RunFile is one-to-many and the relation Runfile <-> Message is also one-to-many. Thus, this query will return the same run multiple times. Maybe there is a way to limit the number of results in a join. I'll look into it. Thanks!